# Azure - the right strategy for MicroServices

Tags: azure, paas

I have been busy breaking up a monolithic service layer into about 30 small 'chunks' that can be independently deployed  (C#, web API).

At the same time, we are moving to Azure. 
How should these microservices be deployed?

We need 4 environments (devint, QA, UA and Prod) so we were going to use 4 slots per PaaS, and a new Paas for every microservice. 
But this would get expensive and hard to manager.

Are there better approaches? (I know little to nothing about Azure so any help is appreciated).

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at Service Fabric?

Comment: A little. Would I have to change my services to use that? One requirement is that the code of the services should not be tied down to a particular platform

Comment: You don't want to be tied to a platform, yet you mentioned that you want to use PaaS.  What do you have in mind when you're saying PaaS?

Comment: What I mean is, if we wanted to migrate to Amazon or IIS, or ohatever...I wouldnt want to have to reprogam the microservices

Answer (score 3):

[Azure Service Fabric](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/service-fabric/) is built for Microservices, and would likely be the best option to go with. Especially for forward thinking when running on the Azure platform. However, depending on your time line the fact that Service Fabric is still in Preview may be an issue. Azure features in Preview don't have the full SLA guarantee that they will when made Generally Available (GA).

The simplest hosting solution to use for Microservices in Azure App Service would be to deploy the different services as **Web Apps**, possibly using Web Jobs for any background processing. Web Apps and Web Jos work extremely well for building Microservices, and I have used this approach on projects in the past.

Regarding you comment about "4 slots". If you are referring to **Web App Deployment Slots**, then you will want to reconsider having 4 deployment slots of the same Web App to host your different environments. Especially in Production, there should be a Deployment Slot used for the Live Production instance, and one slot for a Staging area used for testing deployments before swapping them. When it comes to Dev/Int, QA and UAT then you'll want to have 1 or more Web Apps with necessary Deployment Slots to fit your needs. The last thing you want to do is mix up your Dev/Int, QA, UAT and Production environments. It's also very important to understand that all the Deployment Slots for a single Web App run on the exact same Virtual Machine; which means if you have all 4 environments as Deployment Slots then your Dev and QA environments could affect the performance of Production; which would be horrible.

Comment: Can you still call it a "microservice" when you use multiple azure app services? You can't use any service discovery and I guess you alse have to hardcode service urls etc etc.. Not trying to be rude, just curious.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. You should consider using Azure Web Apps to host your chunks because it doesn't require any customization of the API or Websites you code (unlike Cloud Services which have their packaging and deployment format). The same WebDeploy mechanism will work on any IIS server (on your own server, AWS or Azure)
2. Take a look at [Azure Resource Manager (ARM)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/resource-group-overview/) to define the underlying resources such as the hosting App service plan (equivalent to a web server), web apps and databases. You will in all likelihood have the same set of resources in each environment and different configuration (such as different API URLs) or minor tweaks (such a premium SQL plan or larger/more instances of the web applications). ARM template can thus be shared across the 4 environments with each environment having its own ARM parameter file.